# c# how do I use a method in a Windows Forms App?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I just need something basic.  I am trying to call a method from a button click and I don't know if I declare an object and method in Program.cs or Form1.cs

Here is what I have so far.

```
    public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    Form form = new Form();

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtC.Text = form.CalcHypotenuse(double.Parse(txtA.Text), double.Parse(txtB.Text));
    }

}

public string CalcHypotenuse(double sideA, double sideB)
{
    double hypotenuse = Math.Sqrt((sideA * sideA) + (sideB * sideB));
    string hypotenuseString = hypotenuse.ToString();
    return hypotenuseString;
}
```

Comment: Does this give you an error?

Comment: Yes two errors, "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" and "'Form' does not contain a definition for 'CalcHypotenuse'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods need to be inside a class. Your form is a class so just put the method inside it and then you can call it. Please note I have moved the method inside the `frmMain` class and removed the line `Form form = new Form();` since you do not need it.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{    
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // the 'this' is optional so you can remove it
        txtC.Text = this.CalcHypotenuse(double.Parse(txtA.Text), double.Parse(txtB.Text));
    }

    public string CalcHypotenuse(double sideA, double sideB)
    {
        double hypotenuse = Math.Sqrt((sideA * sideA) + (sideB * sideB));
        string hypotenuseString = hypotenuse.ToString();
        return hypotenuseString;
    }

}
```

If you are only calling the method from within your form only, then make it private too so it can not be called from outside.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked.  Didn't know I needed to use 'this'